# S3 Client PutObjectRequest throws WebException

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am having a problem with PutObject on S3, and keep receiving the following WebException

**"A redirect was returned without a new location. This can be caused by attempting to access buckets with periods in the name in a different region then the client is configured for."**

The code I am using is very simple:

```
AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretAccessKey);

PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
request.WithBucketName("my.url.com");
request.WithKey("myfilename.txt");
request.FilePath = filePath;
request.ContentType = podcastFile.PostedFile.ContentType;
request.StorageClass = S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy;
request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
client.PutObject(request);
```

Could anybody shed any light on this?

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What region is your bucket in?

You might need to specify the correct URL to connect to via:

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
{
    ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
    CommunicationProtocol = Amazon.S3.Model.Protocol.HTTPS,
};
```

and then using that config as part of your call to CreateAmazonS3Client.

Comment: Thanks Joe! Who'd of thought it'd be so simple :)